# Python raises the MemoryError exception when running with Slurm?

Tags: python, slurm

I was running a python script via Slurm on a cluster. The script raised the MemoryError exception when it attempted to read data line by line from a file. The piece of code where the exception was raised is shown as attached. It could happen at either line 2 when the fread is iterated, or line 4 when a line is splitted. I requested as large as the memory that the node has, and MaxRSS showed only a small fraction of the requested memory was used. That is, this is not because I did not request enough amount of memory.

[image]

However, the weird thing is that when I ran the code directly on the node (exactly the same one that I submitted the Slurm job at), there was no error.

I guess Slurm has some constraints on memory usage so that Python cannot fully use the memory I requested? Any ideas or experience with such an issue?

Comment: I guess that the most relevant to this question are how you submitted, i.e. which options did you include in you job-script. Can you please show us this? Also, never included screenshots of code, one cannot much with this. Finally, try to make a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in this case for example by simply allocating a very large random NumPy-array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Tom. I will edit the question later.

Comment: What is the result of the `ulimit -a` command on the submission node?

Comment: Thanks. Memory usage is unlimited. Running the script directly on the node raised no exception. @damienfrancois

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with Slurm. Finally I rebooted the entire system and the issue was solved. Doubt if this is a Slurm bug, i.e., after running for sometime, Slurm is prevented from fully use the requested memory (could only use 8GB in my case although 100GB was allocated).